# SpringUtilities.java (SpringLayout)

Tags: java, swing

Кто может подскажать, как именно можно модифицировать эту версию утилиты, что бы она не меняла высоту элементов(необходимо лишь, что бы максивальная высота учитывалась для отступа вниз). Планируется один из элементов JtextArea, но все доугие однострочные по высоте. Хотелось бы сохнанить выравнимание в строке по верху.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringFormProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java

Comment: используется так SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0);